# Update InfoPath Form Field From SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am building a form where we have one field which changes every month.  Users using the form can't edit this, but obviously those will full control can.  I have set the default value in the list column, but it does not transition to the form.  The form, for some reason, is publishing with the hard-coded value associated with the initial form, and I have to go into InfoPath to manually hard-code the new value in.  Is there a way to get this form to automatically read from the SharePoint list, and pull in the amended default value?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

- You need to promote the form field from InfoPath to SharePoint (which will link them), 
  or
- use the list as a data source and add the logic to update that field.

If all you do is link a InfoPath item to the list data source field, that will be a read in operation, you need to create a rule somewhere that writes back to the field when it is updated in the form.

Comment: Is there somewhere where I could find the procedure on doing these processes?  Everything I have found is for InfoPath 2010, and I'm on 2013, so I'm not seeing some of the same features.  I have tried to get these fields linked, and tried to create a rule, but I am obviously missing something simple, and feel silly.

Comment: Is there somewhere where I could find the procedure on doing these processes?  Everything I have found is for InfoPath 2010, and I'm on 2013, so I'm not seeing some of the same features.  I have tried to get these fields linked, and tried to create a rule, but I am obviously missing something simple, and feel silly.